# State machine reflexive transition

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

In WF 4.0 a reflexive transition does not cause the state entry actions to re-run if the transition happens.

In my opinion this is not a transition, but a contained behaviour. A reflexive transition should leave and re-enter, but WF 4.0 finite state machine does not behave like this.

What formal specs apply here and what consensus is there on reflexive transitions and their effects on states, state entry or exit behaviours, and how does wf 4.0 sit with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "reflexive transition" you mean "self-transition," then yes I believe the exit and entry events should be fired again.  In short, this is where you transition to the state that you are already in...